# Как добавить строку в таблице с помощью JS?

Tags: javascript, html

[image: При методе function addRow() { let table = document.getElementById("mine_info"); table.insertRow(); При нажатии на кнопку появляется пустая область, а не строка]
При методе `function addRow() {let table = document.getElementById("mine_info"); table.insertRow();`
При нажатии на кнопку появляется пустая область, а не строкаЕсть таблица:

```
<tr>
        <th>№ п/п</th>
        <th>Какая-то инфа/th>
        <th>Какая-то инфа</th>
        <th>Какая-то инфа</th>
        <th>Какая-то инфа</th>
        <th>Какая-то инфа</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p>Какая-то инфа</p></td>
        <td><p>1</p></td>
        <td><p>Какая-то инфа</p></td>
        <td><p>Какая-то инфа</p></td>
        <td><p>Какая-то инфа</p></td>
        <td><p>Какая-то инфа/p></td>
    </tr>
    <input class="button" type='button' value='Добавить'>
```

Хочу чтобы при нажатии на кнопку на кнопку добавлялась пустая новая строка. Куда я потом что-то запишу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте метод **insertRow()**

```js
function addRow() {
  let table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  let row = table.insertRow();
  let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  let cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  let cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  let cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  let cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
  let cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
  cell1.innerHTML = "№";
  cell2.innerHTML = "Какая-то инфа";
  cell3.innerHTML = "Какая-то инфа";
  cell4.innerHTML = "Какая-то инфа";
  cell5.innerHTML = "Какая-то инфа";
  cell6.innerHTML = "Какая-то инфа";
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>№ п/п</th>
      <th>Какая-то инфа</th>
      <th>Какая-то инфа</th>
      <th>Какая-то инфа</th>
      <th>Какая-то инфа</th>
      <th>Какая-то инфа</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
         <p>1</p>
      </td>
      <td>
         <p>Какая-то инфа</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Какая-то инфа</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Какая-то инфа</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Какая-то инфа</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Какая-то инфа</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input class="button" type='button' value='Добавить' onclick="addRow()">
```

Comment: Попробовал этот метод, и он работает странно. Он добавляет пустое место, но не столбцы. Попробуйте сами нажать на своём комментарии выполнить код и поймёте о чём я. В любом случае огромное спасибо (может я не прав или ещё что-то т.к я нуб ещё)

Comment: Обновил ответ, добавил столбцы

Answer (score 2):

> Хочу чтобы при нажатии на кнопку на кнопку добавлялась пустая новая строка. Куда я потом что-то запишу

Такое можно проделать таким образом...

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', _ => {
  const table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  const r = document.createElement('tr')
  table.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(_ => r.insertCell().innerHTML = '<br />')
  table.querySelector('tbody').insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', r)
})
```

```html
<table id="myTable" border='1'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>№ п/п</th>
      <th>Какая-то инфа</th>
      <th>Какая-то инфа</th>
      <th>Какая-то инфа</th>
      <th>Какая-то инфа</th>
      <th>Какая-то инфа</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button>Добавить</button>
```